# Using urldecode functions in Bash script fails: a%xyb results in ayb (xy are digits)

Tags: bash

`deurlname` froms `renameutils` renames files properly, though it ignores `%xy` in folder path.

But so far I have found no function that works on strings in Bash script.

What I have tried so far:

1.

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias urldecodePython='python3 -c "import sys, urllib.parse as ul; print(ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1]))"'
fnonly=$( urldecodePython "$fnonly" )
```

2. 

```
urldecode() {
    # urldecode <string> ,  assumes the data contains no backslash.

    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}
fnonly="$(urldecode "$fnonly")"
```

3. 

```
fnonly=$(echo "$fnonly" | sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g')
```

4. 

```
rename 'use URI::Escape; $_ = uri_unescape $_' $fdir/*%*
```

(Before I switched to `deurlname`; not a string function but had the same problem.)